# Amish Friendship Bread starter with buttermilk

Tags: baking, bread, starter, buttermilk

I saw a recipe for an Amish Friendship Bread that called for buttermilk in the starter and feedings.  *If* I made this and gave some away, are the recipients now required to continue to feed the starter with buttermilk or can they feed it like a normal starter?  I don't want to make this one if it is forever required to "eat" buttermilk.

Comment: If the feedings you need to do require buttermilk, then yes, so will your friends'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Probably not...**

Though there are plenty of starters that include [dairy](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/node/16030/buttermilk-starter-can-i-keep-it-going), instant mashed potatoes, fruits, etc to inoculate or feed the starter; the goal of any starter culture is to grow and maintain a of yeasts that can efficiently and effectively raise bread, normally *wheat* or *rye*-based bread.  Any ingredient added to a starter other than water and wheat/rye, in my opinion, only increases the chances of ruining a perfectly good starter through contamination. The species of yeasts and bacteria that flourish in milk or on fruit may lead to off-flavors.  In [cultured buttermilk](http://www.webexhibits.org/butter/buttermilk.html) (widely available in the US) the milk is first pasteurized then inoculated with a mixture of bacteria to produce the tangy flavor and thicker texture.  Unfortunately, this often includes bacteria from the [genus Leuconostoc](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/node/10901/pineapple-juice-solution-part-2) which are known to cause off-flavor in starter cultures and their resultant breads.

**On the Other Hand...**

Unlike sourdough starters (where a procession of bacteria acidify the mixture to the point where only wild yeast and certain bacteria will happily live there) your buttermilk starter probably has a pH around 4.5.  This is the pH where commercial yeast functions optimally, lower than that (pH 4) the yeast will produce less gas, a lot lower (pH 3) they won't produce any gas at all and may die off.  Refreshing the starter regularly with a mixture of buttermilk and flour provides food for the yeast and helps maintain that optimum pH.

If your friend stopped feeding the starter with the buttermilk mixture and just used a flour & water mixture, I suspect it might stop leavening properly.  As the bacteria from the original buttermilk keep working they will acidify the culture,  over time it could reach a point where the commercial yeast is inhibited, and if it is kept covered in the fridge there probably won't be enough wild yeast to raise the bread.

**In conclusion...**

If you or the person you plan to share this starter with is likely to feed/refresh it regularly with the buttermilk mixture, then by all means try it out.  If not, you're probably better off just starting a more traditional sourdough starter.  You can always add milk or buttermilk when making dough to get the flavor and texture you want without the risk of contaminating your starter.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I wouldn't mind trying it once, but since buttermilk is so expensive compared to milk (or even water!), I don't want to be committed to it or force someone else to be committed to buttermilk.